# NLog output directory discrepancy in ASP.Net Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog

NLog is configured to write logs to this location:

```
<variable name="logDirectory" value="${aspnet-appbasepath}\Data\Logs" />
```

I have the follow code setting up my ASP app:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var logger1 = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger1.Info("Hello World");
    
    WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    ...
    // logging
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Host.UseNLog();
    
    ...
    WebApplication app = builder.Build();
}
```

`logger1` is writing files to `C:\Foo\Bar\bin\Debug\net6.0\Data\Logs`

If I inject an `ILogger<T>` somewhere else in my app the logs are instead written to `C:\Foo\Bar\Data\Logs`.

How can I make `Logger1` write to `C:\Foo\Bar\Data\Logs` instead of `C:\Foo\Bar\bin\Debug\net6.0\Data\Logs`.

- I'm aware can create a logger that writes where I wish via `app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()` however I need a logger before `app` exists.
- `logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();` also writes to `\bin`.

Comment: The logic for resolving ContentRootPath is here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/master/src/Shared/LayoutRenderers/AspNetAppBasePathLayoutRenderer.cs If you have improvements for a better fallback logic, when logging before having called `builder.Build()`, then you are very wellcome to create a pull-request: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pulls

Comment: Created https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/887 that will be included in the coming release of NLog.Web.AspNetCore

Answer (score 0):

NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.2 has been released, that [now prioritize current-directory](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/887) for `${aspnet-appbasepath}`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore